# Select Where datatables con php y Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datatables

tengo un sistema que permite cargar documentos y para cada documento escribir sus comentarios, esta parte ya funciona pero necesito mostrar los comentarios que fueron escritos para dicho documento usando [Datatable](https://datatables.net/). 
Este es mi codigo:

> Tabla.php

Esta es la tabla con id="tabla_comentarios" y muestra los datos de mi datatable

```
<table id="tabla_comentarios" class="table display responsive no-wrap" width="100%">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Titulo</th>
  <th>Comentarios</th>
  <th>Autor</th>
  <th>Fecha</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Atravez de esta variable se que documento es    $idDocument=$_GET['id'];

> Datatable.js

En otro archivo, tengo la definición de mi datatable, en la parte de ajax obtengo todos los comentarios, creo que la solución seria enviar una variable con el id del documento.

```
var tabla_comentarios;

$(document).ready(function() {
  tabla_comentarios = $("#tabla_comentarios").DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "ajax": "../../phpcrud/select_comentarios.php",
    "order": [],
    "scrollX": true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons:
    [
      { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copiar'},
      { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' },
      { extend: 'pdf', text: 'Pdf'},
      { extend: 'print', text: 'Imprimir' },
      { extend: 'csv', text: 'Csv'},
      { extend: 'colvis', text: 'Eliminar Columnas' }
    ]
  });
});
```

> Select_comentarios.php

```
    <?php
    require_once '../php/db_connect.php';
    $output = array('data' => array());
    $idDocument=$_POST['idDocument'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comentarios";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);

    $x = 1;
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output['data'][] = array(
            $x,
            $row['titulo'],
            $row['comments'],
                $row['idusuario'],
                $row['fecha'],
        );
        $x++;
    }

    $connect->close();
    echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que preguntas es cómo mandar el dato a $_POST['idDocument'] en select_comentarios.php:

```
'ajax': {
    'url': '../../phpcrud/select_comentarios.php',
    'type': 'POST', 
    'data': {
       idDocument: variable_con_ID_documento,
    },
}
```

Y si lo quieres sacar por $_GET, pues usa el método GET.

Pero no entiendo que quieres hacer, si es una página con un documento y sus comentarios relacionados, seria mejor imprimir todo a la primera con una sóla consulta a la BDD y luego convertir la tabla normal a Datatables, no veo la necesidad de una segunda consulta por AJAX, salvo que tengas miles de comentarios para cada documento y quieras paginarlos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ha sido de gran ayuda tu respuesta